# Calculated @balance return null

Tags: mysql

```
select 
transaksi_perantara.debet, transaksi_perantara.kredit, 
@balance := @balance + transaksi_perantara.debet - transaksi_perantara.kredit AS balance from transaksi_perantara;
```

The balance column return NULL.

Comment: You need to initialise the variable. Also, without an ORDER BY clause, this appears to be rather meaningless :-(

Comment: @Arnaud i run it in php my admin bro and the result of the balance column is NULL

Comment: @Strawberry can you show me how ?

Comment: There are thousands of examples here and elsewhere- see if you can figure it out first

Comment: i try to initialise with (select @balace :=0) AS variableInit at the end of syntax but return still NULL

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your table's data structure, It is hard to give straight to the point answer.

However, I can say that one of your columns includes null values and summing/subtracting value to/from null results with null.

*`@balance` is definitely null in your case*

you can replace your columns with IFNULL

```
select 
  transaksi_perantara.debet, 
  transaksi_perantara.kredit, 
  @balance := IFNULL(@balance,0) + 
    IFNULL(transaksi_perantara.debet, 0) - 
    IFNULL(transaksi_perantara.kredit,0) 
  AS balance from transaksi_perantara;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id_trx,debet,kredit,
       @saldo:=@saldo+debet-kredit as saldo from transaksi_perantara,
       (select @saldo:=0) AS variableInit;
```

Comment: Could you add any commentary to your answer? Explain your logic, and give a little commentary on what your code is intended to do. This will help the OP, but it will also serve as commentary for future users.